# For some reason, I'm getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Tags: arrays

For some reason, I'm getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7`.

```
public void distance() {
    double velocity [] = {20,25,30,35,40,45,50};
    double angle [] = {25, 30,35,50,45,50,55};
    double [][] distance= new double[7][7];

    for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;i<7; j++)
        {
            distance[i][j]= (Math.pow(velocity[i], 2) * Math.sin(2*angle[j]))/9.81;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could the inner (j) loop be checking the wrong variable (i < 7)? I don't think the inner loop will ever terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is checking `i < 7` instead of `j < 7`.

Comment: omfg! thank you so much. I can't believe I didnt see that. Seriously, thank you.